# Thickening cream in a blender to increase fat content?

Tags: ice-cream, whipped-cream, consistency, fat

I've established that it's not possible(or a compromise at best) to mix other things in single cream to increase its fat content.

I have 25% and 30%(rarer) cream available where I'm at, and I'd like to have whippable cream with a fat content of 35% or more to use in homemade ice cream.

I've considered and rejected the following methods already:

1. Adding gelatin. This recipe is vegetarian so gelatin is not an option. I have not tried agar-agar or carrageenan yet.
2. Mixing butter in the cream or whole milk. This'll lead to a grainy ice-cream so, no.

Is a blender or food processor an option? If a cream can be thickened using a centrifuge, will a blender be powerful enough to thicken it by separating out the buttermilk?

If not, what else can I do? Heating the cream on a low flame?

Comment: You can whip 25% fat content cream.

Comment: @GdD yes, but it takes a long time(~15 minutes of continuous whipping while maintaining a cold bowl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The centrifuge doesn't thicken the cream by mechanical action, but by separating the fat and water by their different densities.  The blender allows you to spin, but not to draw off either liquid.  There's a chance that when allowed to settle you'll get layers, but you're more likely to [make butter](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-blender-butter-228225) so you'd have to stop just in time, then let it settle.

It might be worth experimenting with freezing the cream - not until solid but until ice crystals form - and then allowing it to defrost in the fridge without stirring.  This should break the emulsion and cause it to separate, hopefully into layers.

Comment: Is that why the cream separates into thick and thin (thick on top, milk-like thin on bottom)? Could I just separate the thick part and use it as-is?

Comment: If your cream separates, then yes, the top will be fat-rich and the bottom more watery, just as the cream floats on milk that hasn't been homogenised

Comment: I'll try it and see, thanks! Does this happen with both 25% and 30%?

Comment: Another question: does the liquid that remain on the bottom contain any fat at all? Or is it just milk?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a small difference in the starting fat percentage to change the behaviour, but  differences in processing might (e.g. if they're different brands).  Neither part will be pure,  and milk can contain up to a few percent fat anyway.  I'd use up the bottom as milk, and if trying to work out the fat content of the top, accept that  there's some uncertainty

Comment: Update, I tried freezing and cooling the cream, and it curdled :( Is this normal?

Comment: Freezing cream is not recommended - it becomes quite grainy on thawing. I don't think you can separate some of the water out of it afterwards, but even if you can, the result is still rather unpleasant.

Answer (score 3):

The blender is not a centrifuge, and you will achieve the opposite effect. You will homogenize the milk further, as opposed to separating it.

In general, there aren't ways to "force" milk to become cream at home. Since you already have cream, if you just want it a bit more dense, you can instead add a bit of mascarpone while whipping.

Since you mention ice cream though, you don't need high-fat cream for that. In fact, pure whipping cream at 30-33% is too high fat for ice cream, so recipes will typically use a mixture of milk and cream instead of pure cream.

If you absolutely need thicker cream for another reason, you can buy unhomogenized cream without stabilizers and leave it in the fridge for a week or two before using it. Then you can separate the thicker layer on top from the thinner layer on the bottom. I mention this for completeness only, since it is usually more practical to buy the thicker cream.

Comment: So 25% is good enough? I just want to make it airier by whipping, but it is harder to whip if the fat content is low. I am also going to add sweetened condensed milk to add the "milk" flavor and sweeten the ice cream.

Comment: I honestly wish I could tick both answers...

Comment: Indeed, 30% is considered the border between whippable and not. I have never seen an ice cream recipe that adds whipped cream, the cream is always added in liquid (or thickened) form. If you want more overrun, the classic way of doing it is to buy a machine that runs at a higher speed.

Comment: There's a channel on YouTube named Nino's Home that makes ice cream using hand-whipped 36% cream, condensed milk, and cocoa powder.

Comment: This description is very far from traditional ice cream, but if you like it, go for it! If you can't get the 36% cream, I would suggest trying the added-mascarpone route for that mixture.

Comment: I haven't made it yet and I'm not sure about the mascarpone, but I'll try it and report back.

Comment: Hey, so I have an update. I tried the 30% cream and turns out it's just fine for whipping - there's really none of that liquid that I feared would be there - the one that settles down in the case of 25% cream. It also doubled in size quite quickly and I was able to make ice cream out of it. I quite like it, actually!

Comment: Glad you had success with your recipe! Yes, 30% cream whips, that's why producers have chosen that percentage to sell. There are chefs who prefer more fat for a richer taste or for the more stable foam, that's where the tricks come in. But if you don't need that extra, it's even easier. Enjoins your ice cream.

Comment: Next time I'm thinking of using some carrageenan in the recipe, because when I put it in the fridge to set, I notice it's let out some air. Also, I'm looking for a way to make it slightly lighter. As it is now, it's difficult to eat more than one serving of it. But ah the taste...!